# freemarkerConfiguration issue when upgraded from Spring 4.2.2 to 4.3.3

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration"
    class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean"
    p:preferFileSystemAccess="false" p:templateLoaderPath="classpath:/" />
```

Works in Spring 4.2.2 but when I upgraded to 4.3.3 throwing exception on server startup.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: freemarker.template.Configuration.(Lfreemarker/template/Version;)V

freemarker version: 2.3.20

java version: 1.8.0_60

Comment: upgrade freemarker to latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Configuration(Version)` was added in FreeMarker 2.3.21. It's beneficial to use the latest version anyway (2.3.25 ATM).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the classical implementation:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
   <property name="templateLoaderPath"><value>/WEB-INF/freemarker/</value></property>
</bean>
```

or

```
 <bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
   <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
 </bean>
```